# Transforming from .gltf to .jsx is not working

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gltf

I am developing a react app with threejs. I wanted to use 3d object in my project, therefore, I followed `https://github.com/CesiumGS/gltf-pipeline` and implemented `npm install -g gltf-pipeline` then downloaded a 3d model(chair) then run `gltf-pipeline -i scene.gltf -o chair.gltf -d` then from `https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx` I run `npx gltfjsx chair.gltf --transform` but doesn't convert chair.gltf to chair.jsx.
Message in the terminal as below:

```
prune: No unused properties found.
prune: No unused properties found.
instance: No meshes with ≥5 parent nodes were found.
prune: Removed types... Node (1), Scene (1)
prune: No unused properties found.
prune: No unused properties found.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRoot')
    at Vt (file:///C:/Users/Mostafizur%20Rahman/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/gltfjsx/node_modules/@gltf-transform/functions/dist/functions.modern.js:1:35043)
    at file:///C:/Users/Mostafizur%20Rahman/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/gltfjsx/node_modules/@gltf-transform/functions/dist/functions.modern.js:1:62906
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at textureCompress (file:///C:/Users/Mostafizur%20Rahman/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/gltfjsx/node_modules/@gltf-transform/functions/dist/functions.modern.js:1:62881)
    at Tt.transform (file:///C:/Users/Mostafizur%20Rahman/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/gltfjsx/node_modules/@gltf-transform/core/dist/core.modern.js:1:33378)
    at async transform (file:///C:/Users/Mostafizur%20Rahman/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/gltfjsx/src/utils/transform.js:108:3)
    at async WriteStream.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/Mostafizur%20Rahman/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/gltfjsx/src/gltfjsx.js:56:11)
```

I tried to solve this solve problem in different ways, but failed.

I wanted to have like this below:
[image]
which meant that the existing chair.gltf file will be converted in chair.jsx file.

Answer (score 1):

```
[github][1]
```

refer this comment i had the same issue, this comment has the right solution

solution: npx gltfjsx@6.2.13 ...